# How to find angle of rotation?

Tags: rotations

$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{lll}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
$$
D=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3} i}{2}\right) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{3} i}{2}\right)
\end{array}\right]
$$

$A$ is the form of the rotation matrix in $(x, y, z)$ basis (orthonormal) and $D$ is it's form in new basis $(x', y', z')$ in which it is diagonal. The rotation occurs about the axis in the direction$$\hat{n}=\frac{\hat{x}+\hat{y}+\hat{z}}{\sqrt{3}}
$$

And the transformation rule between $(x, y, z)$ and $(x', y', z')$ is given as

\begin{aligned}
x &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(x^{\prime}+\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{3} i}{2}\right) y^{\prime}+\left(\frac{-1-\sqrt{3} i}{2}\right) z^{\prime}\right) \\
y &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(x^{\prime}+\left(\frac{\left.-1- \sqrt{3} i) y^{\prime}+(-1+\sqrt{3} i) z^{\prime}\right)}{2}\right)\right.\\
z &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(x^{\prime}+y^{\prime}+z^{\prime}\right)
\end{aligned}
So my question is how to find angle of rotation? Help!

Comment: One simple way would be to take any vector that's orthogonal to the axis of rotation, for example $v = (1, 1, -2)$, and compute where $A$ sends this vector, namely $Av$. Then you simply want the angle $\theta$ between $v$ and $Av$, which you can get from $\cos(\theta) = \langle v, Av \rangle / (\|v\| \|Av\|)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, your rotation is a rotaion around $\left(\frac1{\sqrt3},\frac1{\sqrt3},\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)$. Take a unitary vector $v$ orthogonal to this vector; for instance, take $v=\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},-\frac1{\sqrt2},0\right)$. It happens that$$A.v=\left(0,\frac1{\sqrt2},-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)$$and so the angle $\theta$ that you are looking after is the angle between $v$ and $A.v$. Since these are two unit vectors, $\theta$ is such that $\cos\theta=\langle v,A.v\rangle=-\frac12$, and therefore $\theta=\frac{2\pi}3$.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the columns, under the transformation the unit vectors $i$, $j$ and $k$ are transformed as follows:

$$i \rightarrow j$$
$$j\rightarrow k$$
$$k\rightarrow i$$

Doing the same transformation three times would be equivalent to the identity matrix.
Therefore the matrix is a rotation of $120^o$ about the line $x=y=z$.

Comment: This is a clever observation (+1), but it doesn't tell us whether it's +120 or -120 degrees.

Comment: @Bungo how do you decide what is positive and what is negative in this situation?

Comment: The OP defined the vector of rotation as $(1,1,1)/\sqrt{3}$, so a standard convention would be to define a right-hand coordinate system with that vector as the $z$ direction, then define positive and negative angles in accordance with that system. In any case, no matter how you define +120 and -120, only one of them is actually the correct answer, and unfortunately I don't see how your solution tells us which one.

Answer (score 0):

Rotations in $R^3$ are the compositions of rotations in $R^2$,

A rotation in $R^2$ is written as

$\left(\begin{matrix}
\cos(\alpha)&\sin(\alpha)\\
-\sin(\alpha)&\cos(\alpha)
\end{matrix}\right)$

where $\alpha$ is the angle of the rotation

In $R^3$ you can write it as the product of two rotations in $R^2$
$\left(\begin{matrix}
\cos(\alpha)&\sin(\alpha)&0\\
-\sin(\alpha)&\cos(\alpha)&0\\
0&0&1
\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}
\cos(\beta)&0&\sin(\beta)\\
0&1&0\\
-\sin(\beta)&0&\cos(\beta)
\end{matrix}\right)$

in your example you are sending the:

- $x$-axis to the $y$-axis
- $y$-axis to the $z$-axis
- $z$-axis to the $x$-axis

so you are doing 2 rotations (over 2 different axis) of 90º degrees each

Comment: Quite right, and as a result of this explanation, about the axis of rotation the angle of rotation should be 120°. Thanks

Comment: If you rotate over the axis (x,y,z)=(1,1,1). I guess yes?

Comment: If you do the operation 3 times x-axis go to the y-axis then to the z-axis and finally it ruturns to the x-axis. 120º*3=360º

Comment: Also the projection of the x-axis, y-axis and z-axis onto the plane x+y+z=0 form 120º each.

Comment: No no, you do 120° counterclockwise rotation only once about (1, 1, 1) axis

Comment: We can both visualize it.

Comment: (The plane x+y+z=0 is perpendicular to the axis (1,1,1))

Comment: Yes yes, we can both visualize it!

Answer (score 0):

The trace (the sum of the entries on the diagonal) of a rotation matrix is
$$
1 + 2 \cos \theta
$$
In this case
$$
1 + 2 \cos \theta = 0 \implies \cos \theta = -0.5 \implies \theta = 2\pi/3
$$